# upload jenkins build revision to s3 without triggering codedeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, deployment

I have successfully built my artifacts and uploaded the artifacts with the help of code deploy plugin in jenkins

Now I have a scenario where I'll deploy my revision but will not trigger the codedeploy automatically. I'll login to amazon console and select uploaded revision and trigger deployment.

Is there a plugin to upload only the artifact and not trigger deployment?

Thanks

Comment: Anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the S3 Plugin for Jenkins that can upload any of your built artifacts to S3.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/S3+Plugin